# Using Mongoose, I cannot pull an ObjectId from an Array on another collection

Tags: mongoose

I am aware similar questions exist but none of those answers helped.
I have a Schema object called Product, with the following field:

```
categories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Category" }]
```

So Products can have an array of Categories.
Looking in mongodb it looks like this for a Product:

```
"categories" : [ ObjectId("5dd66ec536199f03339e6ec7") ]
```

Now, if someone modifies this Category which is referenced by the Product, I need to pull it from the array and this is what I cannot get to work with this code:

```
Product.updateMany({}, { $pull: { categories: {_id: "5dd66ec536199f03339e6ec7" } } }, { new: true });
```

To me this looks right. I have also tried to explicitly create an ObjectId (should not be needed in Mongoose 5.x) but it gives me the same result.

If I run this directly in mongodb, it works:

```
db.products.updateMany({}, { $pull: { categories: ObjectId("5dd66ec536199f03339e6ece") } } )
```

Just to test, I tried the same on an array with Strings and it worked just fine

I am running mongoose version 5.7.12

Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong or if I have encountered a bug?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this one out myself. I changed it to the below

```
Product.collection.updateMany({}, { $pull: { categories: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(categoryId) });
```

I did two things:
1. Instead of using {_id: "5dd66ec536199f03339e6ec7"} I created an ObjectId, something I tried this before but it didn't seem to solve the problem.
2. This was my main issue. For whatever reason, Product.updateMany did not work. Instead I had to use Product.**collection**.updateMany

Comment: adding `collection` works for me also  - mongoose v5. it is odd that the docs don't have info about what's the difference between the two different query strategy